# Extracting text between two repeated sets of values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have campaign names that conform to the following structure:

```
[Network] - [Language] - [Country] - [Channel] - [Campaign Type] - [Free Text]
```

This could look like:

```
Google - English - India - Display - Discovery - Test A
```

What I need is a formula in excel or google sheets that helps me extract any of these values I want. For example I'll download the raw data and want to add two columns, one that extracts language, and another that extracts country.

I managed to cobble together this formula (If campaign name is in column D2) that gives me language, but I'm not sure how to adjust it to move to the next value of the string:

`=iferror(MID($D2,SEARCH(" - ",$D2,SEARCH($D2,$D2,1))+3,SEARCH(" - ",$D2,SEARCH(" - ",$D2,SEARCH($D2,$D2,1))+3)-(SEARCH(" - ",$D2,SEARCH($D2,$D2,1))+3)),"")`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Super User is not a script writing service, it's a question and answers site. You need to have at least had a go at it yourself, and let us know where you're stuck. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @spikey_richie I edited to show the formula I'm using to get language. But I'm struggling to make edits to get country. I get a partial country name depending on the length of characters for language.

Comment: Does it have to be a formula? Could you just paste this into a column in Excel and use the "Text to columns" feature to split this up like you would do with a CSV, but using the hyphen as your delimiting character? This will trivially give you every token as a value in its own column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Excel 2013+, you can use the `FILTERXML` function

- create the xml from your string:

  ```
   ="<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(D2," - ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>"
  ```
- then construct an xPath to return the numbered items you desire

So, to extract the language item, you could use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(D2," - ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[2] ")
```

to extract the next item, change the [2] to a [3].

To extract the first, third and fifth items as an array, you could use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(D2," - ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[position()=1 or position()=3 or position()=5]")
```

All kinds of variations depending on exactly what you want to do.

- every odd numbered node:

  ```
   "//s[position() mod 2 = 1]")
  ```
- every even numbered node

  ```
  "//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")
  ```
- The last 2 nodes

  ```
  "//s[position() >= last()-1]"
  ```
- all the nodes separately in an array:

  ```
   "//s"
  ```

If you don't have the `FILTERXML` function, there are other ways of accomplishing this but you'd need to let us know the version of Excel.